# Run external shuffle service in Spark standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark

I'm deploying Spark in standalone mode. In the [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/spark-standalone.html), I don't find how I can run external shuffle service in standalone mode. What command should I use? Or is it even supported?

**Update**

I found `sbin/start-shuffle-serve.sh` in Spark 2.4, but not in Spark 3.1. In Spark 3.1, I only found a `sbin/start-mesos-shuffle-service.sh` which seems to be related but not for standalone mode. Is it no longer supported?

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed supported, see https://books.japila.pl/apache-spark-internals/external-shuffle-service/ and the Spark manuals, e.g. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html. E,g:

Unfortunately hard to follow.

The following:

> In standalone mode, start your workers with
> `spark.shuffle.service.enabled` set to `true`. I.e.
> spark.shuffle.service.enabled to true in the `spark-defaults.conf`
> file for every Worker in your cluster. YARN approach handier I
> believe.
>
> Or do the following in code:

```
 val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("SaveMode test")
                  .master("spark://localhost:7077")                                                              
                  .config("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", true)
                  .getOrCreate()
```

> Start the external shuffle service with `./start-shuffle-service.sh` on
> your cluster.

Note there is also the `spark.shuffle.service.db.enabled` parameter.

https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/external-shuffle-service-apache-spark/read is a good guide here, the manuals are a let down.